# Can you update a github project's README.md without manually forking it first?

Tags: bash, git, github

Here's a common use case for me: I'm trying to install a github project I've never used before. It doesn't go smoothly and I waste 15 minutes (or 15 hours) only to realize, if the README.md had a single line of required information, this ordeal would have taken me 15 *seconds*.

Like a good samaritan, I want to add that step to the README, but the time and effort is like an order of magnitude greater than typing the line in the README.md file: fork the github repo, edit my fork of the README, write a commit message and commit, and create a PR.

Is there a more streamlined way to make these one-off changes to README files?

---

Note:

1. Here's how I'm going to approach it if there isn't a better way: I'm going to install the [github cli](https://cli.github.com/) and automate this in a shell script that takes a github clone url as input.
2. I want to elaborate on what I mean by "manually" in the title: I don't mind using an automated script (I'm using WSL.exe with Ubuntu) to streamline this.

Comment: If you have the  right permissions you can edit in place and commit, otherwise you must crate a PR

Comment: (1) Make the commit (2) `git patch-format` to make a patch file for that commit (optionally pipe to your clipboard) (3) Make an issue “Readme needs an update” (4) paste the patch (which includes the commit message) into the description field as a code block. ((5) Optional: get anger and/or confusion in response)

Comment: @Guildenstern That's some high effort laziness right there. I applaud you. Are you sure step 5 is optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fork the github repo, edit my fork of the README, write a commit message and commit, and create a PR.

This is the right way, if you don't have the GitHub repo's permission.

You are good samaritan, we know, but there may be some "bad samaritans" who wants to destroy some repos, you can see [many](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/734/files) [of](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/683/files) [them](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/658/files) [in](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/562), for example torvalds/linux, or some other famous repositories.

So, a check for repo owner / permissioned user, is necessary, to avoid anyone's annoying attack that wants to destroy the repo. That's why not anyone allowed to direct edit the repo.

However, fork -> edit -> create PR is sometimes seems complex, so GitHub provides the simpler operation:

1. Locate to the file in the repo you want to edit.
2. On the top-right corner of this file, there is a button with icon of a pen, named with "Fork this repository and edit the file". Click it.
3. You will be asked for forking the repository, if you don't have permission to this repository.
4. Edit this file with your mind.
5. Apply it, this will create a branch in your fork, and automatically<sup>maybe, I didn't try this when writing the answer.</sup> create a PR for your edit.

Comment: `On the top-right corner of this file, there is a button with icon of a pen, named with "Fork this repository and edit the file". Click it.` This is exactly what I was looking for! This is so strange because I feel like I've clicked this pen/pencil icon in the past, but I've never noticed it forks for me. But after clicking it today, I don't see how I could've missed that. FWIW, I think the fork is created after step 2, not during step 4. If you can clarify that detail, I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @DanielKaplan I updated my answer: I tried this answer (to step 3), then found that new fork is created after step 2, and the (original) step 4 actually create a branch in the fork.

Answer (score 2):

The [`gh pr create` command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) will automatically (will prompt you for confirmation) create a fork for you if youre trying to create a PR on a repo you don't have push access to, so this can be automated with a bash script like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

# Create a temporary directory and cd into it
TEMP_DIR="$(mktemp -d)"
cd "$TEMP_DIR" || exit

# First argument is the repo URL, second is the file to edit
# defaults to README.md
REPO="${1?Pass the repo URL as the first argument}"
FILE="${2:-README.md}"

# Clone the repo, cd into it
git clone "$REPO"
cd "$(basename "$REPO")" || exit

# Prompt for branch name, create it
read -rp "Branch name: " BRANCH
[[ -z "$BRANCH" ]] && exit 1 # exit if the branch name is empty
git checkout -b "$BRANCH"

# open the file in $EDITOR, default to nano if not set
"${EDITOR:-nano}" "$FILE"

# Commit the changes
git add "$FILE"
git commit

# open a PR, will fork if needed
exec gh pr create
```

This will, of course, require you to [install and setup `gh`](https://docs.github.com/en/github-cli/github-cli/quickstart) beforehand